# How to left join two tables and display info?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 3 tables: 
`miners` with columns `id` and `name`;
`users` with columns `id`, `name` and `password`;
`user_miners` with columns `user_id` and `miner_id` (foreign key to those other tables)

I need to print out users and their miner names
so for example i have user with id 1, and he has miners with names f,s,t
So i would need to print out:

```
1 f
1 s
1 t
```

how do i do that using left join?

I've tried all the possible left joins but i cant seem to get it working, maybe simply because i don't understand the concept of left join

```
    ('SELECT user_mineres.user_id, users.id, miners.name
    FROM user_mineres
    LEFT JOIN users
    ON user_mineres.user_id=users.id
    LEFT JOIN miners
    ON users.id=miners.name
    GROUP BY user_mineres.user_id ');

    foreach ($stmt as $row) 
    {
    echo $row['user_id'] . $row['name'] . "<br>";
    }
```

i get errors that the column names are ambiguous or other syntax errors

Comment: When you have multiple tables with the same column name, you have to prefix the column name with the appropriate table name in your `SELECT` clause.  That is the source of your "column names are ambiguous" errors.

Comment: Whats the purpose for the group?

Comment: I read that GROUP BY is necessary if you're doing more than 1 left join

Comment: May be here you are getting wrong `users.id=miners.name`.how can you join id with name

Comment: The group is not necessary to do multiple joins

Comment: no `GROUP BY` is not necessary

Comment: now it prints out the user id's, but no names next to them. I have no idea how to join the names with the user id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `group by`, only the proper joins and the proper ON clauses:

```
SELECT u.id, m.name
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_miners um ON um.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN miners m ON m.id = um.miner_id
```

Comment: The table name in question is `user_mineres`

Comment: In the question it's `miners` in the code it's `mineres`. I don't know which is correct and which is a typo.